# How do I get global variables in python to work within a list?

Tags: python, list, global-variables

```
global globalEnd
globalEnd = 0

aList = [0,globalEnd,[0,1,globalEnd]],[[],['l'],globalEnd]

for i in range(10):
   globalEnd += 1
   print(aList)
```

Like the code above I want all the values called globalEnd in the list to be 10. But it still prints out 0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use an `object`, which will be updated if any of its attributes gets updated-

```
global n

class node:
    age = 0

    # The returned value is printed whenever you print the object of this class
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.age)

def print_list(l):
    ind = 0
    while(ind < len(l)):
        if(type(l[ind]) is list):
            print_list(l[ind])
        else:
            print(l[ind], end=", ")
        ind = ind+1

def main():
    global n
    n = node()
    lst = [0, n, [n, 0]]

    print("initially : ")
    print_list(lst)
    print("\n")

    # Modify the age
    count = 0
    while(count < 10):
        n.age=n.age+1
        count = count+1

    # See if it gets updated
    print("post update: ")
    print_list(lst)
    print("\n")

main()
```

Output :

```
initially :
0, 0, 0, 0,

post update:
0, 10, 10, 0,
```

Comment: Thx! This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This issue has nothing to do with global variables. In fact, you could remove the redundant statement `global globalEnd` and still observe the same result.

The problem is that you are not mutating `globalEnd` with the line `globalEnd += 1`. You are building a new integer with the value of `globalEnd + 1` and reassign the name `globalEnd` to that value.

`aList` in turn does not get mutated, because it still holds references to the original value of `globalEnd`.

Since there is no way to mutate the value of an integer, you will have to either mutate `aList` directly or build a new list and reassign the name `aList`. I suggest the second option.

Demo:

```
>>> globalEnd = 0
>>> 
>>> aList = [0,globalEnd,[0,1,globalEnd]],[[],['l'],globalEnd]
>>> 
>>> print(aList)
([0, 0, [0, 1, 0]], [[], ['l'], 0])
>>> 
>>> for i in range(10):
...     globalEnd += 1
...     aList = [0,globalEnd,[0,1,globalEnd]],[[],['l'],globalEnd]
...     print(aList)
... 
([0, 1, [0, 1, 1]], [[], ['l'], 1])
([0, 2, [0, 1, 2]], [[], ['l'], 2])
([0, 3, [0, 1, 3]], [[], ['l'], 3])
([0, 4, [0, 1, 4]], [[], ['l'], 4])
([0, 5, [0, 1, 5]], [[], ['l'], 5])
([0, 6, [0, 1, 6]], [[], ['l'], 6])
([0, 7, [0, 1, 7]], [[], ['l'], 7])
([0, 8, [0, 1, 8]], [[], ['l'], 8])
([0, 9, [0, 1, 9]], [[], ['l'], 9])
([0, 10, [0, 1, 10]], [[], ['l'], 10])
```

I very much recommend Ned Batchelder's talk "Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values".

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns)
[Article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

The fact

> Fact: Names are reassigned independently of other names.

is especially relevant to your question. If you reassign the name `globalEnd`, the references in `aList` which are pointing to the original value do not care.

Comment: Is there anyway to make globalEnd an object then? So everywhere I have globalEnd, if I update it, it is updated everywhere without transversing the list. I'm currently implementing ukkonen's algorithm for suffix tree's and I need a way to update the leaves by + 1 for all leaves with globalEnd (the rapid leaf extension trick).